# Hide only the word "Previous" from a DT datatable in R

Tags: r, dt

I would like to hide only the word "Previous" from the pagination menu of a DT:datatable. If this is not possible I would also like to hide the word "Next" as well but certainly not the page numbers.

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the next and previous by changing the `pagingType`:

```
DT::datatable(iris, options = list(pagingType = 'numbers'))
```

See [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType) for other options